# Update detail dates based on datediff from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a question, which I do not really know how to solve.

I have two tables.

1. `Header`: `Header_ID`, start dates and duration in months
2. `Detail`: `Det_ID`, `Header_ID`, Months (start date until start date + duration).

Sample data:

Headertable:

| Header_ID | Start_date | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-21 | 4 |
| 2 | 15-10-21 | 3 |
| 3 | 18-10-21 | 2 |

Detail table:

| Det_ID | Header_ID | Months |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01-01-21 |
| 2 | 1 | 01-02-21 |
| 3 | 1 | 01-03-21 |
| 4 | 1 | 01-04-21 |
| 5 | 2 | 15-10-21 |
| 6 | 2 | 15-11-21 |
| 7 | 2 | 15-12-21 |
| 8 | 3 | 18-10-21 |
| 9 | 3 | 18-11-21 |

Now I am looking for a SQL script to update the detail based on a change in start date of the header table.

For example if in the header table, Header_ID number **3** start_date is modified from 18-10-2021 to 20-12-2021, detail should be updated to:

| Det_ID | Header_ID | Months |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01-01-21 |
| 2 | 1 | 01-02-21 |
| 3 | 1 | 01-03-21 |
| 4 | 1 | 01-04-21 |
| 5 | 2 | 15-10-21 |
| 6 | 2 | 15-11-21 |
| 7 | 2 | 15-12-21 |
| **8** | **3** | **20-12-21** |
| **9** | **3** | **20-01-22** |

How can I update this via a script in SQL Server?

I cannot just delete the `Header_ID` in the detail table and recalculate and reinsert it based on the header table, because there are much more details in the detail table that will be lost.

Perhaps via a CTE?

Something like:

1. Select minimum of Months for every header ID in detail table to compare detail with header
2. Calculate date difference between Header table and minimum of months of detail table.
3. Dateadd in detail table for every ID based on the datediff in 2.

Hopefully somebody could help me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using triggers?

Comment: Images of data don't help us help you, take the time to post it in a consumable format.

Comment: Pictures make no sense (and are bad for SO). Why shall details for header 3 start 2 months after the header 3 start date when header 1 and 2 match first detail start date?

Comment: Ok Updated! It was just an example that only header 3 is changed, so only this detail should be changed.
Triggers can be applied when an update is done, but I need to know how to generate the update script of the details.

Comment: What if the date moves in the other direction and rows need to be deleted?

Comment: In this situation dates will always move foward and the duration will not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only the start date is changing, then presumably the duration is not (for duration changes, you should ask a new question; that is much more challenging).

Basically, you just want to update the values in order.  Let me assume that you know that id 3 is changing:

```
update d
    set month = dateadd(month, d.seqnum - 1, h.start_date)
    from (select d.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by header_id order by  months) as seqnum
          from details d
         ) d join
         header h
         on d.header_id = h.header_id
    where h.header_id = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out with the sample data.

Comment: It worked, the d.seqnum needed to be the second argument. Thanks.

What to do when the header_id is not known? I need to first determine the list of id's where the start_date is not equal to the first month in the detail table and then run the script for all header_id's that are in this list.